# Prove that the functional is unbounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

If $\,C^1[a, b]\,$ is the normed space of continuously differentiable functionals on $\,J=[a, b]\,$ with the norm 
$$
\|x\|=\max_{t\in j}\big\lvert \,x\left(t\right)\big\rvert + 
\max_{t\in j}\big\lvert \,x'\left(t\right)\big\rvert,$$ 
Then $\,f(x)=x'(c)\,$ with $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is a bounded linear functional but when $f$ is considered as a functional on the subspace of $C[a, b]$ of all continuously differentiable functionals it is unbounded.

I proved the first part of the problem as follows:

$$\big\lvert \,f(x)\,\big\rvert = \big\lvert \,x'(c)\,\big\rvert
\le \big\lvert \,x(c)\,\big\rvert + \big\lvert\, x'(c)\,\big\rvert
\le \max_{t \in J}\big\lvert \,x(t)\,\big\rvert + \max_{t\in j}\big\lvert\,x'(t)\,\big\rvert = \left\|x\right\|.$$

I don't know how to come up with a counterexample for the second part.

Comment: Find a sequence of functions such that $\lvert x_n(t)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $t$ and $n$, but $x_n'(c)$ is unbounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does $\sin(n \pi t)$ work here? Then I don't know what to say about $\cos(c)$. It is bounded. Or do standard rational functions work like $1/t^n$?

Comment: It does work, but it's easier to show if you translate the functions a bit, $\sin \bigl(n\pi (t-c)\bigr)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your help. I don't follow, however, why its important that $\|x_n(t)\|$ be $\le 1$?

Comment: That's not important. What we need is that $$\frac{\lvert x_n'(c)\rvert}{\sup \{ \lvert x_n(t)\rvert : t \in [a,b]\}}$$ is unbounded. Keeping $\lVert x_n\rVert_\infty = \sup \{\lvert x_n(t)\rvert : t \in J\}$ bounded is just something that simplifies verification.